# Error [ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE]: Premature close in Node Pipeline stream

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, etl, node-modules, node-streams

I am using the `stream.pipeline` functionality from Node to upload some data to S3. The basic idea I'm implementing is pulling files from a request and writing them to S3. I have one `pipeline` that pulls zip files and writes them to S3 successfully. However, I want my second `pipeline` to make the same request, but unzip and write the unzipped files to S3. The pipeline code looks like the following:

```
pipeline(request.get(...), s3Stream(zipFileWritePath)),
pipeline(request.get(...), new unzipper.Parse(), etl.map(entry => entry.pipe(s3Stream(createWritePath(writePath, entry)))))
```

The s3Stream function looks like so:

```
function s3Stream(file) {
    const pass = new stream.PassThrough()
    s3Store.upload(file, pass)
    return pass
}
```

The first `pipeline` works well, and is currently operating greatly in production. However, when adding the second pipeline, I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE]: Premature close
at Parse.onclose (internal/streams/end-of-stream.js:56:36)
at Parse.emit (events.js:187:15)
at Parse.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at Parse.<anonymous> (/node_modules/unzipper/lib/parse.js:28:10)
at Parse.emit (events.js:187:15)
at Parse.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:641:14)
at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:481:3)
at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:471:7)
at /node_modules/unzipper/lib/PullStream.js:70:11
at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:480:3)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Any idea what could be causing this or solutions to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### TL;DR

When using a pipeline you accept to consume the readable stream fully, you don't want anything stopping before the readable ends.

### Deep dive

After some time working with those shenanigans here is some more usefull informations.

```js
import stream from 'stream'

const s1 = new stream.PassThrough()
const s2 = new stream.PassThrough()
const s3 = new stream.PassThrough()

s1.on('end', () => console.log('end 1'))
s2.on('end', () => console.log('end 2'))
s3.on('end', () => console.log('end 3'))
s1.on('close', () => console.log('close 1'))
s2.on('close', () => console.log('close 2'))
s3.on('close', () => console.log('close 3'))

stream.pipeline(
    s1,
    s2,
    s3,
    async s => { for await (_ of s) { } },
    err => console.log('end', err)
)
```

now if i call `s2.end()` it will close all parents

```
end 2
close 2
end 3
close 3
```

> pipeline is the equivalent of s3(s2(s1)))

but if i call `s2.destroy()` it print and destroy everything, this is your problem here a stream is destroyed before it ends normally, either an error or a return/break/throws in an asyncGenerator/asyncFunction

```
close 2
end Error [ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE]: Premature close
    at PassThrough.onclose (internal/streams/end-of-stream.js:117:38)
    at PassThrough.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at emitCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:81:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE'
}
close 1
close 3
```

---

You must not let one of the streams without a way to catch their errors

> stream.pipeline() leaves dangling event listeners on the streams after theallback has been invoked. In the case of reuse of streams after failure, this can cause event listener leaks and swallowed errors.

[node source (14.4)](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/streams/end-of-stream.js#L114)

```js
  const onclose = () => {
    if (readable && !readableEnded) {
      if (!isReadableEnded(stream))
        return callback.call(stream, new ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE());
    }
    if (writable && !writableFinished) {
      if (!isWritableFinished(stream))
        return callback.call(stream, new ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE());
    }
    callback.call(stream);
  };
```